# How to access element by an object's field in Actionscript-3 E4X dot operation?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

In Actionscript 3, we can access a XML object in a E4X style like:

```
var a:XML =
    <book>
        <title>ABC</title>
    </book>;
trace(a.title);
```

But what if we get the tag name from within an object or class?

```
trace(a.Constants.BOOK_TAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trace(a.children()[0].name());
```

Comment: thanks for your prior answer. I find a way I thought for today.

Answer (score 0):

I read a piece today answering my question:

```
trace(a.[Constants.BOOK_TAG]);
```

the square bracket notation works for use parameter in E4X.